# Update column from join fails

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, sql-update

I want to update a column in table 2 with the data from a column in table 1 based on the comparison of another column in table 2 and table 1.

Ex.:

[image]

I used this script:

```
DECLARE

    TYPE dataRows_t IS TABLE OF table1.tagid%TYPE
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    Tag   dataRows_t;
    tempTag dataRows_t;

BEGIN

    SELECT t1.tagid, t1.tagidB
    BULK COLLECT INTO Tag, tempTag
    FROM table1 t1;

    FORALL indx IN 1 .. Tag.COUNT
        UPDATE table2 t2
        SET t2.tagid = tag(indx)
        WHERE t2.tempTagIdB = temptag(indx);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Which works OK for up to 40k lines (around 3 minutes to complete)

My next try at 60k had not finished after 10 minutes.

I tried the total 89k lines for 9 hours and did not complete.

However, when I cancelled the script I could see that the values had been updated properly but the script had not finished.

I'm aware that checking a condition on 89k lines is probably not the most efficient but I did not find any better solution and I imagined it would complete in less than one hour.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you could do this with a single MERGE statement

Answer (score 1):

I would try a MERGE instead:

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2
USING (SELECT tagid, tagidB from table1) t1
ON t2.tagidB = t1.tagidB
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  t2.tagid = t1.tagid
```

Regarding your comment "when I cancelled the script I could see that the values had been updated properly but the script had not finished.". When you run a block of PL/SQL code, the entire block is sent to the DB server and executed there. If you cancel the operation in your client program, that does not cancel the execution of the code block in the database.  Your observation indicates that eventually it finished executing and the changes were committed (since your code block includes a commit).  If you didn't have a commit in the PL/SQL block, it would have been rolled back after it completed when it detected that the client session was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use correlated subqueries instead of a loop. This should work in Oracle (assuming no duplicate `tagIdB` in `table1`):

```
update table2 t2
set t2.tagid = (select t1.tagid from table1 where t1.tagIdB = t2.tempTagIdB) 
where exists(select 1 from table1 where t1.tagIdB = t2.tempTagIdB)
```